# assign same quantity of work by each worker available php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to assign same quantity of work by each worker available in php.

This is my array of available worker:

```
if (!isset($array_worker)){
    $array_worker = array();
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username 
                        FROM group_members 
                        WHERE grp_id = :grp_id 
                        AND statut > 0 
                        AND specification != 2");
$stmt->bindValue(':grp_id', $grp_id);    
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $key => $value){

    if (!in_array($value['username'], $array_worker)){
        array_push($array_worker, $value['username']);
    }
}
```

This array_worker return 2 entries

That is what I have try

```
$n = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count_worknotdone($grp_id); $i++) {

    if ($n >= count($array_worker)){
        $n = 0;
    }

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE work 
                            SET worker = :worker 
                            WHERE grp_id = :grp_id 
                            AND worker IS NULL"); 
    $stmt->bindValue(':worker ', $array_worker[$n]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':grp_id', $grp_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $n++;
}
```

but that assign only the first worker for each work..

What I want for example if we have 2 workers available and 4 work not done

We assign 2 work for each workers.

Thanks you

Comment: You know that `count_worknotdone()` will be called each time the loop condition is evaluated, right? If you are updating the work table during the loop, wouldn't that affect the result of the count? So the loop may terminate early.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($array_worker)){
    $array_worker = array();
}

if (!isset($array_id)){
    $array_id = array();
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM group_members WHERE grp_id = :grp_id AND statut > 0 AND specification != 2");
$stmt->bindValue(':grp_id', $grp_id);    
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $key => $value){

    if (!in_array($value['username'], $array_worker)){
        array_push($array_worker, $value['username']);
    }
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM work WHERE grp_id = :grp_id AND statut < 1 AND worker IS NULL");
$stmt->bindValue(':grp_id', $grp_id);    
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $key => $value){

    if (!in_array($value['id'], $array_id)){
        array_push($array_id, $value['id']);
    }
}

$n = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_id); $i++) {

    if ($n >= count($array_worker)){
        $n = 0;
    }

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE work SET worker = :worker WHERE id = :id AND grp_id = :grp_id AND worker IS NULL");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $array_id[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':worker', $array_worker[$n]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':grp_id', $grp_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    

    $n++;
}
```

I have done what I want by doing that, that for sure can be improve but its working..